# ArrayList Is Empty Outside the Coroutine Scope

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I'm building a project based on Android MVVM Architecture. I wrote my own API to get the Ddta. The API returns an ArrayList of cloths. I use *Retrofit* for calling the API. The Repository class works fine and it returning the list from the API but the problem occurred in the ViewModel.

When I access the ArrayList inside a *coroutine* its works fine ( using coroutine because getClothList is a Suspend function inside the Repository class ) but I'm not able to access that ArrayList outside the scope of coroutine.

> clothlist is empty outside the viewModelScope

**View Model**

```
class ClothViewModel(private val repository: ClothRepository) :ViewModel() {
    lateinit var clothList:ArrayList<ClothModel>
 init {
     viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
      clothList = repository.getClothsList()
      Log.d("ClothList ->",clothList.toString())
     }
 }
     fun getData():ArrayList<ClothModel>{
         clothList = repository.clothsList
        Log.d("View Model ->",clothList.toString())
         return clothList
    }

}
```

**Repository Class**

```
class ClothRepository(private val clothService: ClothService) {

   val clothsList = ArrayList<ClothModel>()
     suspend fun getClothsList():ArrayList<ClothModel>{
         val result = clothService.getClothList()
         if (result?.body() != null) {
            clothsList.add(result.body()!!)
         }
       Log.d("Result ->",result.body().toString())
        return clothsList
     }
}
```

**Main Activity**

> Since I'm not getting the List in viewModel I am unable to used it inside the mainActivity

```
class WelcomeScreen: AppCompatActivity() {
     var arrayList = ArrayList<ClothModel>()
    var arrayList1 = ArrayList<ClothModel>()
    lateinit var viewModel :ClothViewModel
    var state =1
    lateinit var firebaseAuth:FirebaseAuth
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard)

        val clothService = ClothHelper.getInstance().create(ClothService::class.java)
        val clothRepository = ClothRepository(clothService)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,ClothViewModelFactory(clothRepository)).get(ClothViewModel::class.java)
        arrayList = viewModel.getData() //calling the viewModel function
        setupADapter()
    }
      fun setupADapter(){
           var list = listOf("Nike","Romans","CK","Jordan","Kizumik","Hishida")
           var recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.cloths)
             Log.d("Passing ->",arrayList1.toString())
            recyclerView.adapter = ClothViewAdapter(arrayList1)
            recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(applicationContext,2)
      }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my function that calls an API return an empty or null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value). Your coroutine takes time to execute, but you are trying to get the data immediately. You can [use a LiveData](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70178210/9473786) to post the values once your routine fetches them.